# MediaWiki make table row a link

Tags: php, mediawiki

I have many pages where I am going to have tables of data that will link to other pages. Is there an easy way to make a whole row link to a different page without having to link each cell?

Not in HTML but in wiki code

Comment: what is wiki code?

Comment: I dunno...they didn't read the question really

Comment: No, you can't. And yes, this shouldn't have been marked as a duplicate.